# Missing a step in my webpack config output

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

I've been trying to follow the example of [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) on GitHub in setting up my `webpack.config.prod.js` file.

This is my `webpack.config.prod.js` file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './main.js'],

  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'main.prod.js'
  },

  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },

  target: 'electron-main',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],

  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-3']
            }
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
        { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'},
        { test: /.(ttf|eot|otf|svg)(\?v=[0-9].[0-9].[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("^(fs|ipc)$")),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
      'process.env.WEBPACK_DEV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
  ]
}
```

So this file outputs `main.prod.js` to the root directory, cool.

I see in the `electron-react-boilerplate` project, that there are 2 webpack files, a `config.base` and a `config.main.prod.js` which imports `config.base` and does a `merge.smart` with the `base` config as a starting point.

Here's the base config from the Github project:

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import { dependencies as externals } from './app/package.json';

export default {
  externals: Object.keys(externals || {}),

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      }
    }]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1114
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },

  /**
   * Determine the array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
   */
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

and the `webpack.config.main.prod.js` from the Github project

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import BabiliPlugin from 'babili-webpack-plugin';
import { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

export default merge.smart(baseConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  target: 'electron-main',

  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/main.dev'],

  // 'main.js' in root
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './app/main.prod.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    /**
     * Babli is an ES6+ aware minifier based on the Babel toolchain (beta)
     */
    new BabiliPlugin(),

    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      analyzerMode: process.env.OPEN_ANALYZER === 'true' ? 'server' : 'disabled',
      openAnalyzer: process.env.OPEN_ANALYZER === 'true'
    }),

    /**
     * Create global constants which can be configured at compile time.
     *
     * Useful for allowing different behaviour between development builds and
     * release builds
     *
     * NODE_ENV should be production so that modules do not perform certain
     * development checks
     */
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'),
      'process.env.DEBUG_PROD': JSON.stringify(process.env.DEBUG_PROD || 'false')
    })
  ],

  /**
   * Disables webpack processing of __dirname and __filename.
   * If you run the bundle in node.js it falls back to these values of node.js.
   * https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2010
   */
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
});
```

Notice the two `output`s in the two config files, one which outputs to `./dist/bundle.js` and the other which outputs to `./app/main.prod.js`.

**In my project, right now I don't have any notion of the `/dist/bundle.js`, so when I build my app and run it, I just get a white screen with no css/js.**

I know I need to include reading a bundle.js script in my `index.html` file, right now nothing is writing out to a bundle.js file, so I need to remedy that.

I'm not sure how to remedy this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit: adding my app's package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "productName": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "main.prod.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.17.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "electron": "^1.6.11",
    "electron-packager": "^8.7.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.1.3",
    "eslint": "^3.13.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/electron .",
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
    "electron-rebuild": "./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild",
    "webpack": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --optimize-minimize",
    "package": "electron-packager . --mac --icon='./assets/icons/mac/icon.icns' --overwrite"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.22.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "electron-context-menu": "^0.8.0",
    "gl-react": "^2.2.9",
    "gl-react-hue-rotate": "^1.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "rc-slider": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dnd": "^2.2.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.2.4",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.14.3",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: how does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: I'll edit and add it right now